# C# GetResponseStream() return not full links

Tags: c#, getresponsestream

Get a page using the httpWebRespond check the received text with the debugger and see that the links are not complete, i.e. If the code of page look in firefox like

```
<a href = "http:\www.server.ru\mainpage.asp"> </a>
```

but after getting html page by GetResponseStream () I see the following

```
<a href = "mainpage.asp "> </a>.
```

How did receive a response full of links?

Comment: Difficult to say, but it's likely a difference in the request you sent--perhaps in the request headers?

Comment: fiddler the two requests and compare them

Comment: I thought fiddler was a real verb you were using till i googled it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout don't. Relative url's are perfectly acceptable per the RFCs. They are to be interpreted **by the User Agent** (that's you) as relative to the *current url* (that being the URL you retrieved whose content returned the relative URLs.)

You need to make them relative to that URL, so a relative URL like `foobar.html` on a page whose full URL is `http://somedomain/alpha/bravo/charlie/index.html` gets converted to `http://somedomain/alpha/bravo/charlie/foobar.html`.